# ASP.NET Server-side Flow Authentication and getting access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need some help here.
I'm trying do come up with a [server-side flow authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) with the below code (it is a ASP.NET button)

```
protected void ServerSide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(
        "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=***************&redirect_uri=MYURI&scope=email,offline_access,&response_type=token"
    );
}
```

However, when the button is clicked, and the user click on Allow button after sign in to Facebook, the browser URL path on the Address bar shows something like the below:-

```
http://MYURL#access_token=***************%7Cd4aa713668298c84a9f74c19.1-***************%7C295Xjb6r-PvLc_l-rKOJ-Lbk5gI&expires_in=0
```

How do I get something like the below in order for my server to post back to facebook with my app secret?

```
http://YOUR_URL?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `response_type=token` from the URL. That is used for client side flow.